# How can I find all four digit numbers from string?

Tags: python

I have a very long string of numbers:

```
str = '0922035963126927190699198371937793731321758941428713'
```

First of all, I want to find all numbers containing four digits:

```
n = 4
chunks = [str[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str), n)]
```

As a result I have numbers like '0922' or '0359'. But how can I make this code to find all of those four digit numbers in string in range of 1000-9999? (without '0' at start)

Comment: `if str[i] != '0'`?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts? Checking `str.startswith()`, converting to int and back to str and checking length, etc?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are really finding all four digit numbers. For example at the end, you find `8713` but not `2871`...is that your intention? With this in mind, if you skip `0922` do you want to find `9220` or skip all the way to `6312`?

Comment: You can use next regular expression: [`(?=([1-9]\d{3}))`](https://regex101.com/r/QZD0Zj/1).

Comment: @OlvinRoght that regex will find a lot more numbers that the OP's chunking code does (hence my question in the comment above).

Comment: @Mark, it will find exactly *"all four digit numbers from string"*. If question exists we could suppose that something is wrong with solution from this question.

Comment: I understand what the regex does @OlvinRoght — I'm just saying the OP's intention is not clear. They seem to be happy with their code except for the inclusion of numbers less than 1000.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*If* the expected output is:

```
['9220', '3596', '3126', '9271', '9069', '9198', '3719', '3779', '3731', '3217', '5894', '1428']
```

Then a very simple regular expression will find your results:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"[1-9]\d{3}")
>>> numbers = '0922035963126927190699198371937793731321758941428713'
>>> pattern.findall(numbers)
['9220', '3596', '3126', '9271', '9069', '9198', '3719', '3779', '3731', '3217', '5894', '1428']
>>>
```

Comment: This fails on an example suggested above: `numbers = '111108'`

Comment: It doesn't "fail" on that case. As stated, the answer assumes from evidence provided that the OP is looking for 4 digit numbers that don't start with a `0` and are not overlapping. If the numbers can have overlapping digits, then we would expect `['1111', '1110', '1108']`.

Comment: That's not how I understood OPs needs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the condition at the end of the for, that `str[i]` must be different from `0`:

```py
chunks = [str[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str), n) if str[i] != '0']
```

Comment: Do not use `str` as a name of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
string = '0922035963126927190699198371937793731321758941428713'

size = 4
nums = [string[i:i + size] for i in range(len(string) - size + 1) if string[i] != '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it as the other answers suggests! I made it recursive with this function below:

```
input_string = '0922035963126927190699198371937793731321758941428713'

n = 4

def make_chunks(input_string):
    if len(input_string) < 4:
        if input_string[0] == '0':
            return make_chunks(input_string[1:])
        else:
            return print(input_string)
    else:
        if input_string[0] == '0':
            return make_chunks(input_string[1:])
        else:
            print(input_string[0:n])
            make_chunks(input_string[n:])
```

Comment: This fails to properly filter on input like `input_string = '111108'`

Comment: Edited with some error handling like the one you suggested